# Cannot update a component (`HotReload`) while rendering a different component (`Router`)

Tags: next.js13

I'm trying to create a modal in nextjs13 using intercepting an parallel routes as is explained here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/intercepting-routes#examples

My page.tsx looks like this:

```
import { PersonData, getPersons } from "@/lib/person-repository";
import Link from "next/link";

export default function Home() {
  const persons = getPersons(10, 23232);

  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
      <div className="z-10 max-w-5xl w-full items-center justify-between font-mono grid grid-cols-2 gap-8">
        {persons.map((person) => (
          <Person key={person.id} {...person} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

My modal code is under @modal/(.)person/[id]

When i'm clicking the link i get an error message:
*Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).*

And in the console there's the error message from the title:
*Cannot update a component (`HotReload`) while rendering a different component (`Router`).*

I read somewhere that i should check the useState usages in the affected components. But since both components "HotReload" and "Router" are nextjs components, i'm not sure what to do

I just noticed that everything is working fine when im running my project with `npm run build && npm run start`. With `npm run dev` the error occurs.